# OpenCL/C++ - Returning a cl::Buffer object

Tags: c++, opencl

I have the following code to store a point cloud in my GPU Buffer:

```
cl::Buffer writePointCloudToGPU(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>& pointCloud){
    cl_int err;
    cl::Buffer bufferCloud(getContext(), CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(pcl::PointXYZ) * pointCloud.size(), NULL, &err);
    getQueue().enqueueWriteBuffer(bufferCloud, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(pcl::PointXYZ) * pointCloud.size(), const_cast<float*> (&pointCloud.points[0].x), NULL);
    return bufferCloud;
}
```

Will this cause issues with memory leaks when I return a cl::Buffer? Once I return the bufferCloud object, when does the program call release on it?

Comment: For version 1.2, there is a release() in destructor, which, is called when instance is out of scope(when you return it is destroyed after copy constructor worked, when you assign it to a variable, again a destructor called after copy constructer called, then when it is outof scope, its destructor is called). For version 2.0+, there are smart pointers inside so some better usage could be there. Maybe copy elision working inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<CL/cl2.hpp>` OpenCL Wrappers use OpenCL API Reference Counting to keep track of your uses of `cl::Buffer` or any other kind of opencl object, so while I don't recommend just dropping all uses of `cl::Buffer &` or `cl::Buffer const&` or so on (because Reference Counting always comes with a price...) it is, logically speaking, perfectly safe to copy those types: You can think of them as being wrappers around `std::shared_ptr<cl_mem>` or some similar construct, provided you understand that they're not *actually* using `std::shared_ptr`.

The immediate consequence of that, as far as I'm aware, is that the reference counting is not guaranteed for calls across multiple threads. But if your program is properly designed, all the calls to the OpenCL API should be happening on a single dedicated thread, so that shouldn't be an issue.